# Does purge actions incurs in any cost in the Azure CDN?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

i hear/read sometimes comments saying there is a cost for purge content cached in the Azure CDN. I was trying to validate this in the microsoft online documentation but i did not find anything. Do you have any idea if there is any cost in relation with purge in the Azure CDN?

Answer (score 0):

Pricing calculator for Azure CDN doesn't specify "purging" as any criteria for cost estimation. so I believe  just purging wont cost anything.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/?service=cdn

Note: Purging content forces next request to fetch fresh copy of contents which might cost.

you might want to check features related to purging which affect cost in various plans
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-features